# Is there a way i can do multiple inserts into one table using a condition?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there a way i can do multiple inserts into one table using a condition?

i have a list of subscribers in tbl_subscribers. i have an update on productX so i would like everyone who is subscribes to productX to get a notification. The user_notification table is `id PK, user_id, notification_id`. The two values i need is product_id (productX) which allows me to find a list of subscribers in tbl_subscribers and the notification_id to insert into the user_notification table.

How can i do this insert using one query? I see you can do a select statement in sqlite http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html but i cannot wrap my head around how i may do this nor seen an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into user_notification(user_id, notification_id)
select s.user_id, @notification_id 
from tbl_subscriber s 
where s.product_id = @productX
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking from INSERT SELECT as outlined here:

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html

> The second type of INSERT INTO allows
>   us to insert multiple rows into a
>   table. Unlike the previous example,
>   where we insert a single row by
>   specifying its values for all columns,
>   we now use a SELECT statement to
>   specify the data that we want to
>   insert into the table. If you are
>   thinking whether this means that you
>   are using information from another
>   table, you are correct. The syntax is
>   as follows:

```
INSERT INTO "table1" ("column1", "column2", ...) 
SELECT "column3", "column4", ... FROM "table2"
```